# Why Name not showing in textbox based on combobox selected id

Tags: c#

I using below code but it's not showing name in textbox.\

```
 private void AllotLeaves_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        display();
    }
    private void display()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.......");
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from Emp_Details", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds, "Emp_Details");
        cballotid.DataSource = ds.Tables["Emp_Details"].DefaultView;
        cballotid.DisplayMember = "ID";
        cballotid.ValueMember = "ID";

    }
    private void cballotid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=......");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Name from Emp_Details where ID=@ID", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cballotid.Text);
        Object temp = command.ExecuteScalar();  // this returns the first value of the select statement.
        if (temp != null)
            txtallotname.Text = temp.ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it temp...null? Put a breakpoint there...

Comment: code seems tobe fine, you shouldbe able to find out the solution if you debug and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  cballotid.DisplayMember = "Name";
  cballotid.ValueMember = "ID";
  cballotid.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Reference: [ListControl.DisplayMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this

```
cballotid.DisplayMember = "ID";

cballotid.ValueMember = "ID";
```

to

```
cballotid.DisplayMember = "name of field youd like to display";

cballotid.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line as below:-

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cballotid.SelectedValue);
```